# twitter bootstrap 3.3.6 less

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to compile the less of twitter bootsrap but I am getting multiple deprecated packages and some errors.

Here is my log from terminal

```
npm install
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.12: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
bootstrap@3.3.6 C:\projects\alfred\node_modules\bootstrap
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! path C:\projects\alfred\node_modules\bootstrap
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! errno -4082
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\projects\alfred\node_modules\bootstrap' -> 'C:\projects\alfred\node_modules\.bootstrap.DELETE'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\projects\alfred\node_modules\bootstrap\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "name": "bootstrap",
        "raw": "bootstrap",
        "rawSpec": "",
        "scope": null,
        "spec": "latest",
        "type": "tag"
      },
      "C:\\projects\\alfred"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "bootstrap@latest",
  "_id": "bootstrap@3.3.6",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_installable": true,
  "_location": "/bootstrap",
  "_nodeVersion": "0.12.7",
  "_npmUser": {
    "email": "getbootstrap@gmail.com",
    "name": "twbs"
  },
  "_npmVersion": "2.11.3",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "name": "bootstrap",
    "raw": "bootstrap",
    "rawSpec": "",
    "scope": null,
    "spec": "latest",
    "type": "tag"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-3.3.6.tgz",
  "_shasum": "8de8f749dc8a743f2ac5b510d988371e3daa6589",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "bootstrap",
  "_where": "C:\\projects\\alfred",
  "author": {
    "name": "Twitter, Inc."
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": "The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "btoa": "~1.1.2",
    "glob": "~6.0.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~3.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "~0.14.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.14.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jade": "~0.15.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-csscomb": "~3.1.0",
    "grunt-exec": "~0.4.6",
    "grunt-html": "~5.0.1",
    "grunt-jekyll": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-jscs": "~2.3.0",
    "grunt-saucelabs": "~8.6.1",
    "grunt-sed": "github:twbs/grunt-sed#v0.2.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~3.3.0",
    "markdown-it": "^5.0.0",
    "npm-shrinkwrap": "^200.4.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "8de8f749dc8a743f2ac5b510d988371e3daa6589",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-3.3.6.tgz"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.1"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "fonts",
    "grunt",
    "js/*.js",
    "less/**/*.less",
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "LICENSE"
  ],
  "gitHead": "81df608a40bf0629a1dc08e584849bb1e43e0b7a",
  "homepage": "http://getbootstrap.com",
  "jspm": {
    "files": [
      "css",
      "fonts",
      "js"
    ],
    "main": "js/bootstrap",
    "shim": {
      "js/bootstrap": {
        "deps": "jquery",
        "exports": "$"
      }
    }
  },
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "less",
    "mobile-first",
    "responsive",
    "front-end",
    "framework",
    "web"
  ],
  "less": "less/alfred.less",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./dist/js/npm",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "email": "bigj95t+bsnpm@gmail.com",
      "name": "twbs"
    }
  ],
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "style": "dist/css/alfred.css",
  "version": "3.3.6"
}
```

I also added a new file in less director named alfred.less because I only want the twitter bootstrap to be used inside the selector of #alfred

```
#alfred {                        
        @import "bootstrap.less";
}
```

Comment: You probably have the bootstrap folder open in an IDE or somewhere and it is locking it.

Comment: @Mardoxx no, I did not

Comment: sudo npm install npm -g